# Pipe a list of files into vlc and mpc

Tags: windows-7, command-line, vlc-media-player, media-player

I'm trying to pipe a list of all my files that start with "m" in my music folder. This line grabs all of my filenames correctly. I'm using windows 7 command line.

```
dir /s /b | findstr -i -r "\\m[^\\\\]*\...."
```

into vlc media player or mpc media player like so:

```
dir /s /b | findstr -i -r "\\m[^\\\\]*\...." | "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -
```

and I have also tried

```
dir /s /b | findstr -i -r "\\m[^\\\\]*\...." | "C:\\Program Files\\MPC-HC\\mpc-hc.exe" -
```

MPC can take stdin since version 1.7.0 and I'm using the latest versions of both MPC and VLC. When vlc.exe executes, it keeps trying to play something called "fd://0" in the playlist and freezes. With MPC, it just says that it has failed to render the file but has "stdin" in the playlist.

Although I'm using Windows, solutions in Linux would also be appreciated.